# Button in infowindow for Google Maps iOS SDK

Tags: swift, button, google-maps-sdk-ios, infowindow

I want to add a button to the info window to navigate to next page in my iOS app. The didTapInfoWindow method is not working. Is there any way to add the button within the window without using callout views

Comment: see this https://medium.com/@matschmidy/how-to-implement-custom-and-dynamic-map-marker-info-windows-for-google-maps-ios-e9d993ef46d4